# How to cache a webpage using web programming?

Tags: php, asp.net, python, language-agnostic

1. I want to write a web application, which takes the snapshot of the webpage as it is now. **By snapshot I don't mean photo/image/picture**. Instead I want to save the webpage along with javascripts , CSS & images used in the webpage. If there are frames, I need to detect them too and do the same for frame source URLs.

   I other words, I want to exactly do what archive.org has been doing.
2. I'm unable decide up on the language for implementation of this. Could you help me with this too?
3. **EDIT :**  Also, can any one kindly address the storage of these snapshots of webpages as the number of them increases over time? My idea was to create a Unique ID to the snapshot (may be timestamp), create a directory named unique id (timestamp) and store all the snapshot files in that directly and then store reference and meta information about snapshot in database. Is there any thing wrong with my approach? Is there any better approach?

Comment: i will recommend you php for this. it has lot of FILE IO Wrappers and Functions and some other extra extentions. you will be allright with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with any language that has a descent HTML parser. Hoewever, you migth also want to look at [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) which has a nice "mirror" feature and does link rewriting for you.

Comment: Actually `wget --mirror` was the first thing that popped into my head, certainly the easiest approach with simpler sites.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a great library from scraping websites called [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/0.10/index.html). It has tons of features and great docs. Alternately you can write your own scraper using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/howto/urllib2.html), or [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/), [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/)...etc...lots of tools available. One of the first things I did when I learned Python was write a scraper, I don't think you'll find it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This link shows how, using VB.NET, to scrape all links from a page.

http://www.consultsarath.com/contents/articles/KB000017-web-scraping--extract-all-links-from-a-web-page-using-vbnet.aspx

You would use a similar method to obtain links to all images, scripts, etc.

Then, you need some logic to determine which of those referenced files to download.

You'd want most images, but perhaps not all of the scripts. (Do you really want a copy of jquery for each webpage? Best to hash these in a central location probably).

I'd stay away from PHP for this. Python or VB.NET are logical choices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick, over-simplified Python recursive downloader, to give you an idea of how [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) could be used together to archive pages and linked assets.  Handles images and scripts at the moment:

```
import cookielib, os, lxml.html, re, urlparse, urllib2

re_unsafe = re.compile('[^\w\.]')
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*[urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)])

def fetch(url):
    return opener.open(urllib2.Request(url)).read()

def save(url, data, prefix='assets'):
    path = os.path.join(prefix, re_unsafe.sub('_', url))
    if not os.path.exists(prefix):
        os.makedirs(prefix)
    open(path, 'wb').write(data)
    return path

def archive(url):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(fetch(url))
    for tag, attr in [('img','src'),('script','src')]:
        for node in tree.xpath('//%s' % tag):
            orig = node.attrib.get(attr)
            if orig:
                orig = urlparse.urljoin(url, orig)
                node.attrib[attr] = save(orig, fetch(orig))
    print 'saved', save(url, lxml.html.tostring(tree), '.')

archive('http://www.yahoo.com')
```